# Check if next active record exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In posts controller an object contains all active posts:

```
@posts = Post.where(status: 'active').order(:name)
```

In the view this object is iterated and I have to perform some operations based of the existence of next post.

```
<% @posts.each do |post|
   if post.next_post_exists?
    # do something.
   else
    # delete author. 
   end       
  end 
%>
```

So, what is the best way to check if the next post exists?

```
def next_post_exists?
  #TODO
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take a variable for the current post and then check for the presence of the next post.
For example:

```
<%i=0
@posts.each do |post|
  if @posts[i+1].present?
    #do something
  else
    #delete author
  end
  i+=1
end%>
```

Try this and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post

  def next
    self.class.find_by("id > ?", id)
  end

end
```

And at this point you can do:

```
<% @posts.each do |post|
   if post.next.present?
    # do something.
   else
    # delete author. 
   end       
  end 
%>
```